# Why did the Dothraki not follow Jon?

Tags: game-of-thrones

In *Game of Thrones* season 8 episode 6 Jon kills Daenerys.

As we know from previous seasons, if you kill a Khal you become a Khal and Dothraki will treat you as their leader.

There was no mention of them after Daenerys dies, so what could happen?

Comment: I'm not sure that this rule applies to just everyone... it looks more likely that you actually need to be a Dothraki to become a Khal. They accepted Dany because of the miracle by which she killed the other Khals, plus she was a Dothraki by marriage and she could speak their tongue.

Comment: Dothraki: *"Jon Snow, the Khal of the Great Grass Sea"*. Jon: *"I dun wuntit"*

Comment: The title is a spoiler. I don't know the rules of this community and I'm attempting to write this comment without looking elsewhere on the page, but shouldn't spoilers in titles be avoided? This spoiler showed up in my Hot Network Questions queue. I think there should at least be a spoiler tag at the beginning of the title of the question.

Comment: @littleO Yes, spoilers in question titles should indeed be avoided. However, it's unclear how the Dothraki not following Jon is a spoiler in the first place. But no, we don't put meta tags into question titles.

Comment: It only works like that with Riddick.

Answer (score 27, accepted):

The Dothraki follow strength above all else, betraying someone and stabbing an unexpected victim is more a sign of weakness to the Dothraki than strength so I doubt they would follow him for killing the current Khal[essi].

On top of that Jon was imprisoned and sent to the Night's Watch, another demonstration of weakness to the Dothraki.

Though he had previously shown strength in the battle but towards the end of the series Jon was holding his action which is not accepted for the Dothraki.

These are the reasons for not following Jon.

Comment: Without any corroborating evidence from the episode itself, I feel that the last sentence is entirely opinion based and should be labeled as such.

Answer (score 17):

I don't think you got that rule correctly. Nowhere is stated that "he who kills Khal becomes Khal himself". Otherwise that witch who poisoned Kahl Drogo's wound would become Khal. What usually happens when there is a strong Khal is that two Khalasars clash, people from defeated Khalasar join the winning one. But that means the existing Khal becomes more powerful. The person who killed/defeated Khal doesn't become the new Khal himself, probably gets rewarded.

New Khals are created with prestige and challenge. When the current one dies, prominent warriors declare themselves as Khals and fight position, their warrior fame coming to action in attracting followers from existing Khalasar. For example, Khal Drogo defeated many Khals and his Khalasar was very big. After his death, many warriors proclaimed leadership, attracting various number of people. Neither one wanted to risk immediate fight before consolidating power, so they escaped into the Sea during the night. Don't remember was it in show or books, but I think Jorah mentions that there is a dozen of new Khalasars after Drogo's death.

So, death of Khal would cause revenge, especially from Bloodriders. In addition to this, Jon is a foreigner and stranger to their ways, which they would hardly accept. Dothraki are superstitious and they start following Dany after seeing she can't be harmed by fire. Otherwise, she is the one already breaking their customs which deserves punishment, let alone killing Khals in Vaes Dothrak. So there was no way they would follow Jon, strong or not he may be.

I'm surprised nobody noticed this, but if you want to follow Dothraki rules, then they should all commit suicide :) Normally a Khal has four Bloodriders, but she made them all "blood of her blood" when she rode Drogon in front of them. Their duty when she dies is to take care of body and family, and then commit suicide. I do guess that they are aware that was no normal Bloodrider custom with her, so they just ignored that part.

Answer (score -5):

I thought most of them died fighting the with Jon at Winterfell and then again somewhere, but by the time Jon killed her there weren't many and all those Unsullied had him held prisoner for doing it. Plus Jon wasn't one of them they prolly went home.

Comment: We can see in the previous scene, when Dany speaks to her army, that there are a lot of Dothraki still there.

Comment: And even so, that doesn't change the question.