Where do the Dothraki go after Daenerys dies?
In the finale the Iron Throne, Daenerys addresses the surviving Unsullied and Dothraki, calling for them to help her 'liberate' (from her twisted perspective) the rest of the world- something Jon Snow kills her to prevent.
The Unsullied leave what's left of King's Landing for the island of Naath but what of the Dothraki? Do they return to their homeland? Or do they claim any territory in Westeros?

Related: (Science Fiction & Fantasy SE) What is the ultimate fate of the Unsullied and Dothraki?

The series ends... so there's no more plot after that?

Or slightly more correctly, we'll never know until: a sequel movie or series is made, the author catches up to that point and synchronizes the plots of the books to the series (I haven't read any of the books, so if he has or has not done so, I don't know). Until one of those things happen, it would be sheer conjecture, or opinion, and thus disallowed.

related https://movies.stackexchange.com/questions/105278/what-happens-to-unsullied-after-this-death https://movies.stackexchange.com/questions/101161/why-did-the-dothraki-not-follow-jon

In one of the final scenes where the Stark kids are at the port, bidding farewell to each other, we see Dothraki around. So unless specified otherwise, they might have stayed back as the Kingsguard, or the King's army. Considering Dany killed all the Khals, they were without a leader, and Bran with his powers could have convinced them to stay and serve as the King's army.

This question is asking to write more narrative, not to provide an answer on the existing source material.
